# How do I assign a value to a specific row and column by name?

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to iterate through each row in a dataframe, and to do this - `calculate_distance_from_SnS(row)`, then reassign the returned value (its a number).
The result is that it doesn't save the value under the specific column, what am I missing?

for example:

## DF example

```
A   B   C
1   10  0
2   12  0
```

and I want to do this function `C=A+B` for each row and get to this state:

```
A   B   C
1   10  11
2   12  14
```

I did this:

```
def calculate_distance_from_SnS(row):
```

using DF row and using 2 cols to calculate.

```
for i,row in customers.iterrows():
    row['dist_from_sns'] = calculate_distance_from_SnS(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set values of original `DataFrame`, not by `Series` in loop:

```
for i,row in customers.iterrows():
    customers.loc[i, 'dist_from_sns'] = calculate_distance_from_SnS(row)
```

But if possible, better is use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for processing per rows:

```
f = lambda x: calculate_distance_from_SnS(x['lat'], x['long'])
customers['dist_from_sns'] = customers.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: your first solution worked !, but i didnt understand the second one,
on : customers['cols'].apply(calculate_distance_from_SnS), the columns i using are "lat" and "lng" so it should be:
customers['dist_from_sns'] = customers['lat','long'].apply(calculate_distance_from_SnS)
or i am wrong?

Comment: @Daniel - Added solution for apply, `iterrows` working, but if exist some alternative best avoid it - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-pandas-iterrows-have-performance-issues/24871316#24871316)